# How to tell if an Item is a SPFolder or DocumentSet (through code)

Tags: development, folder, document-set

Currently i am creating an Export and Import Tool for SharePoint 2010 to 2013.

The Export Tool exports a whole list or DocumentLibrary to a File. In my DocumentLibrary i have serveral Document Sets.

In my Code i use this to make a distinction between a Folder and a Document Set:

```
if (ListItems.ProgId == "SharePoint.DocumentSet")
```

This works for now but it feels like this solution is unclean....

Is There a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check if your item content type inherits from `DocumentSet` base content type that is `0x0120D520`.

Using C#:

```
listItem.ContentTypeId.IsChildOf(new SPContentTypeId("0x0120D520"))
```

or

```
listItem.ContentTypeId.ToString().StartsWith("0x0120D520")
```

Answer (score 2):

The base Document Set content type ID is `0x0120D520`, so maybe you could do something like

```
SPContentTypeId documentSetID = new SPContentTypeId("0x0120D520");
if (listItem.ContentTypeId.IsChildOf(documentSetID))
{
    // do something
}
```

Here is the MSDN documentation on the [`SPContentTypeId` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttypeid_members.aspx), take a look at the methods `IsChildOf` and `IsParentOf`.

Comment: I gave the "Correct Answer Tag" to ECM4D because he was faster. But Thanks for Answer anyway :)